# "All" missing from favorites bar in mail on Mavericks

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I used to have a choice "All" on the favorites bar in Mail on Mavericks. (This is on an iMac). It has disappeared.  Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

You can try dragging all mail from the sidebar up to the favourites bar:

[image]

Comment: I don't have an "All Mail" but I do have an "Archive" in the same spot as you have All Mail. Dragging it to the bar worked for me. You might have to click the "Show" button on the left side of the favorites bar.

Answer (score -1):

"All" appears when you search. When not searching, "Inbox" will display all of your received messages.